# R: Problems with testthat test_file() within local environment

Tags: r, testing, environment, testthat

I am having problems with a call to test_file within a local environment.

```
local({ newvar <- 1; expect_equal(newvar, 1); });
```

Works fine.

```
local({ 
  newvar <- 1; 
  test_that('newvar is equal to 1:', { expect_equal(newvar, 1) }); 
});
```

works fine.

```
local( { newvar <- 1; test_file('simple.test.R'); });
```

Error: object 'newvar' not found

Contents of simple.test.R are simply:

```
context('local env test');
test_that('local env test', { expect_equal(newvar, 1) })
```

Help appreciated! Thanks.

---

Edit:

What I'm trying to do is read some code from shinyAce (https://github.com/trestletech/shinyAce), and check it is valid (mets some defined requirements). I was using 'local()' so that any assigned variables defined in the shinyAce block would not remain in the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the source for `test_file`:

```
function (path, reporter = "summary") 
{
    reporter <- find_reporter(reporter)
    with_reporter(reporter, {
        sys.source(path, new.env(parent = globalenv()), chdir = TRUE)
        end_context()
    })
}
```

The key line is this:

```
sys.source(path, new.env(parent = globalenv()), chdir = TRUE)
```

The file is executed in a new environment under the *global environment*, while your `newvar` is only available in a local environment of your creation.

What exactly is your end goal here? We can try to help. Or were you just curious?

Comment: So `newvar` changes across test runs? Within `simple_test.R`, you could create a function that takes a `newvar` parameter and then put all your test logic in there. If you really wanted to, you could also define your own version of `test_file` that evaluates the source file in some other environment. Would one of these work?

Comment: I think writing my own version of test_file is the best solution here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot simply write your own version of `test_file`, because many of the pieces `test_file` uses are not exported: `find_reporter`, `with_reporter`, etc. So you cannot use these in your new `test_file`, which is a pain....

Comment: @GaborCsardi, you would just use the triple colon operator. E.g., `testthat:::find_reporter`.

Comment: That is not allowed in R packages on CRAN

Comment: @GaborCsardi, I don't think that's what the OP is up to here. Nonetheless, I do agree that `:::` has its perils that should be kept in mind.